# using dragtable plugin messing Css

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am using drag table plugin but it's doing something strange when ever i am click for dragging it's css behavior strange i am attaching pic and my can any one tell why it's behaving like that must be appreciated.it's dragging column but on time of dragging looks like.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>DragTableAndMatainDisplayOrder</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">


<style>
    .tftable
    {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #333333;
        width: 100%;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #9dcc7a;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .tftable th
    {
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size: 12px; 
        background-color: #abd28e;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px; border-style: solid;
        border-color: #9dcc7a;
        text-align: left;"
    }

    .tftable tr
    {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .tftable td
    {
        font-size: 12px;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #9dcc7a;
    }

</style>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libraries/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libraries/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libraries/dragtable.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
          console.log("dom ready");
    $('#randomTable').dragtable();

    });

   </script>

</head>

<body>

   <div id="body">

     <table class="tftable draggable" border="1" id="randomTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>SNO</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Total Order</th>
                        <th>Total Amount</th>
                        <th>Total Item</th>
                        <th>Total Sale</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>19/03/2013</td>
                        <td>98</td>
                        <td>34</td>
                        <td>90</td>
                        <td>88</td> 
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>19/03/2013</td>
                        <td>98</td>
                        <td>34</td>
                        <td>90</td>
                        <td>88</td> 
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>19/03/2013</td>
                        <td>98</td>
                        <td>34</td>
                        <td>90</td>
                        <td>88</td> 
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>19/03/2013</td>
                        <td>98</td>
                        <td>34</td>
                        <td>90</td>
                        <td>88</td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `dragtable.css` also.